# what's the escape sequence for hyphen (-) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping

I'm trying to rename a database to a name with a hyphen (-).

```
ALTER DATABASE one RENAME TO one-two;
```

And psql returns an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
```

What should I use as an escape sequence for "-" character or what's the way to do the above?

Note: 
I've tried the '\-' and didn't work as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a hyphen instead of an underscore?

Comment: Yes Bruce, I'm working with a system which is already created and maintained for few years. And this renaming had to be done to be in line with the other database naming conventions for that system. :-)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Double quotes should do it. But you'll have to always use the quoted-identifier everywhere you reference the database.

```
ALTER DATABASE one RENAME TO "one-two";
```

Answer (score 5):

Mix double quotes and single quotes as such:

```
psql --command='create database "db-name-with-dashes"'
```

Answer (score -5):

psql -d  -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "'"uuid-ossp"'";"

Comment: Irrelevant answer