# postgres how to refer to table names with minus signs

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering if there is a syntax to refer to a table name with minus signs in it. For example, I imported a table called `v-water-a` using `shp2psql`, and then did:

```
select * from v-water-a limit 1;
```

and I got an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: select * from v-water-a limit 1;
```

The same query works if the table was named `v_water_a`. Also, the table `v-water-a` is visible in pgadmin3. I tried quote the name with single quotes, but it didn't work.

Should I quote the table name somehow? or is it the name illegal?
This is with PostgreSQL 9.3.5 under Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Use double quotes: `select * from "v-water-a" limit 1;` See the documentation for information on valid identifiers etc: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Aside: [`psql`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/psql/info) is the name of the main client program, [*not* an abbreviation for Postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines).

Comment: This is all well documented in the manual. Please read the link provided by jpw

Comment: @jpw, thanks for pointing out the reference. Is this also standard SQL syntax?

Comment: @TingL Yes, the ANSI standard way is to use double-quotes. This page has information on different options used in various dbms: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Data_structure_definition/Delimited_identifiers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the escape sequence for hyphen (-) in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942759/whats-the-escape-sequence-for-hyphen-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use double-quotes:

```
select * from "v-water-a" limit 1;
```

Documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html